# In a Circle, given segments AC = 13, BE = 6, BE=DE, find AE (E point where segments AC DB cross)

Tags: circles

In a Circle, given segments $\overline{AC}$ = 13, $\overline{BE}$ = 6, $\overline{BE}$=$\overline{DE}$, find $\overline{AE}$ (E point where segments $\overline{AC}$ and $\overline{DB}$ cross)

It is known that when two chords intersect each other inside a circle, the products of their segments are equal. So:
$\overline{DE}$ $\overline{EB}$ = $\overline{AE}$ $\overline{EC}$

Tried Pitagorian and other relations but could not find a way to get the result

[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So: $\;\overline{DE}$ $\overline{EB}$ = $\overline{AE}$ $\overline{EC}$

Hint:   write it as $\;BE^2 = AE(AC-AE)\,$ and solve for $\,AE\,$.

Answer (score 1):

$BE$ is and altitude of $\Delta ABC$ and we know that $\measuredangle ABC=90^{\circ}$.

Thus, $$BE^2=AE\cdot EC.$$
Let $AE=x$.

Thus, $x(13-x)=6^2,$ which says $x=4$ or $x=9$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\overline { DE } \overline { EB } =\overline { AE } \overline { EC } \\ { 6 }^{ 2 }=\left( 13-x \right) x\\ { x }^{ 2 }-13x+36=0\\ \left( x-4 \right) \left( x-9 \right) =0\\ { x }_{ 1 }=4,{ x }_{ 2 }=9\\ \overline { AE } =9,\overline { EC } =4\\ $$